# Reducer Selection in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, reduce, hadoop-partitioning

I have following record set to process like

```
 1000, 1001, 1002 to 1999,
 2000, 2001, 2002 to 2999,
 3000, 3001, 3002 to 3999
```

And I want to process the following record set using HIVE in such a way so that reducer-1 will process data 1000 to 1999 and reducer-2 will process data 2000 to 2999 and reducer-3 will process data 3000 to 3999.Please help me to solve above problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DISTRIBUTE BY`, mappers output is being grouped according to the distribute by clause to be transferred to reducers for processing:

```
select ...
  from ...
distribute by case when col between 1000 and 1999 then 1
                   when col between 2000 and 2999 then 2
                   when col between 3000 and 3999 then 3
               end
```

Or simply

`distribute by floor(col/1000)`